# C# For Loops and doing addition

Tags: c#, loops, foreach

I have a C# class of people and I am trying to total their number of hours:

```
        Person Person1 = new Person();
        Person1.Name = "Paul";
        Person1.Age = 38;
        Person1.actualGender = Person.Genders.male;
        Person1.workedHours = 15.5f;

        Person Person2 = new Person();
        Person2.Name = "Frank";
        Person2.Age = 15;
        Person2.actualGender = Person.Genders.female;
        Person2.workedHours = 5f;
```

I could do it like this:

```
        float TotalHours;
        TotalHours = Person1.workedHours + Person2.workedHours;
```

But how do I actually do it in a foreach loop as I am bound to have more than 2 people.

My class:

```
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public enum Genders { male, female }
    public Genders actualGender { get; set; }
    public float workedHours { get;  set;}
}
```

Comment: you should learn using arrays before `foreach`

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using a list i.e:

construct a list to hold your objects:

```
List<Person> peopleList = new List<Person>();
// call peopleList.add then add your objects
```

then you can iterate over the objects and sum their `workedHours`:

```
float totalHours = peopleList.Sum(p => p.workedHours);
```

using a `foreach` loop:

```
float totalHours = 0;
foreach(Person p in peopleList){
    totalHours += p.workedHours;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the objects in a list and:

If you want general sum, you can do this:

```
var totalHours = people.Sum(p => p.workedHours);
```

If you want worked hours per person, you can do this:

```
foreach (var person in people)
        {
            var sum = people.Where(p => p.Name.Equals(person.Name)).Sum(p => p.workedHours);
            Console.WriteLine(sum);
        }
```

Comment: This line `var sum = people.Where(p => p.Name.Equals(person.Name)).Sum(p => p.workedHours);` is superfluous , unnecessary and will give wrong results when two or more people have the same name. if you want worked hours per person why not just `Console.WriteLine(person.workedHours);` inside the foreach?

Comment: @Aominè, I just use name like example, the correct is a identity field. If you show individually person.workedHours like you show, you didn't sum anothers hours when the list have more than one of same people